# How to save/read a pandas dataframe that has another dataframe in it?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I created a pandas dataframe containing test report information.  It has 11 series, 10 of which are things like the unit's serial number, the test station ID, start time, etc.  The 11th one is another dataframe containing the bulk of the test information like test name, units, limits, and measured value.  In the program the dataframe is named TRF (test report frame).  The 'rpt' series is the test information.  Here's the type check after running the program.

```
In [70]: type(TRF['rpt'][1])
Out[70]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

When it's saved and reloaded using the CSV format, the embedded dataframe reads back in as a string instead of a dataframe.

```
In [71]: TRF.to_csv('testdata.tsv', sep='\t')
In [72]: CSV = pd.read_csv('testdata.tsv', sep='\t')
In [73]: type(CSV['rpt'][1])
Out[73]: str
```

The same thing happens when read_table is used.

```
In [74]: CSV = pd.read_table('testdata.tsv', sep='\t')
In [75]: type(CSV['rpt'][1])
Out[75]: str
```

Using the json format, it reads back as a dictionary.

```
In [80]: TRF.to_json('testdata.json')
In [81]: JSN = pd.read_json('testdata.json')
In [82]: type(JSN['rpt'][1])
Out[82]: dict
```

But pickle works.

```
In [85]: TRF.to_pickle('testdata.pkl')
In [86]: PKL = pd.read_pickle('testdata.pkl')
In [87]: type(PKL['rpt'][1])
Out[87]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

There are several other methods that can be used but these appear to be the most common. I was unable to find an existing discussion of a saving and loading a dataframe with an embedded dataframe before posting this.

The question: Is there a way to make the CSV method work?

Comment: No, you can't make the `.csv` method work because it's just a simple file that has no idea what a DataFrame is. `.pkl` can serialize python objects so when you save a DataFrame with a DataFrame inside of it, that object information is preserved.

Comment: Your DF probably has a MultiIndex or something.\